# No SnapshotStart detected. Might need more exceptions to trigger snapshot collector

Tags: azure

[image]

Anyone ever encounter this problem and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it still usefull, but after reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/azure/azure-monitor/app/snapshot-debugger#how-snapshots-work) i realized that it is necessary to happen at least twice the same exception so that the snapshot is collected

"The default value for ThresholdForSnapshotting is 1. This is also the minimum value. Therefore, your app has to trigger the same exception twice before a snapshot is created."

Answer (score -1):

Please contact us at snapshothelp@microsoft.com and we'll try to diagnose the problem (don't forget to share your Instrumentation Key).
Keep in mind that SnapshotCollector is supported on **Windows Server 2012 R2 and above**.